# UART controller or RS232 controller? Is UART a general word?

Tags: serial-port, uart

I have a question regarding UART controller.

Is UART controller a general name?

i mean that if we use RS-232 protocol, we should name this UART controller, RS-232 controller and if we use RS-485 as protocol, we should call this UART controller, a RS-485 controller and so on?

I've noticed that we **generally** say network controller (protocols:Ethernet, token ring,ATM,..) and if the protocol implemented is Ethernet for example, we say Ethernet controller. Is it a correct comparison between UART controller and Network controller meaing that they both are general names?

Thanks a lot for your clarifications

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming.

Comment: RS-232 and 458 are *electrical* standards, they prescribe the bus.  UARTs are *generic* devices that works with many of these kind of busses, they just know how to handle asynchronous data.  The bus transceiver is a separate chip.  Use electronics.stackexchange.com to ask questions like this.

Comment: @HansPassant - These are not busses, but just comm links.  USB is a bus, just like PCI, that links devices to the host with control, data and power.  An EIA/RS-232 comm link doesn't meet that level of sophistication.

Comment: sorry for asking this question in this forum, but i was not aware of electronics.stackexchange.com at all.

Comment: @HansPassant I like your definition.

Comment: A UART is not a controller (it doesn't *control* another device), so *"UART controller"* is not a commonly-used phrase.  An "Ethernet controller" could be an Ethernet MAC, which does interface with one (or more) PHYs connected by a MII (or variant such as RMII) bus.  Or an "Ethernet controller" could be referring to a PC adapter board for an Ethernet interface.

Answer (score 10):

**Bibliography:**

- [RS-232 vs. TTL Serial Communication - SparkFun Electronics](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/215)
- *communication - USART, UART, RS232, USB, SPI, I2C, TTL, etc. what are all of these and how do they relate to each other? - Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange [http://goo.gl/0q6sIV](http://goo.gl/0q6sIV_)*
- Serial Programming/Typical RS232 Hardware Configuration - Wikibooks, open books for an open world http://goo.gl/uTknU6

**Serial** is an umbrella word for all that is "Time Division Multiplexed", to use an expensive term. It means that the data is sent spread over time, most often one single bit after another. All the protocols you're naming are serial protocols.

**UART**, for Universal Asynchronous Receiver Transmitter, is one of the most used serial protocols. It's almost as old as I am, and very simple. Most controllers have a hardware UART on board. It uses a single data line for transmitting and one for receiving data. Most often 8-bit data is transferred, as follows: 1 start bit, low level, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, high level. The low level start bit and high level stop bit mean that there's always a high to low transition to start the communication. That's what describes UART. No voltage level, so you can have it at 3.3 V or 5 V, whichever your microcontroller uses. Note that the microcontrollers which want to communicate via UART have to agree on the transmission speed, the bit-rate, as they only have the start bit's falling edge to synchronize. That's called asynchronous communication.

> For long distance communication (a that doesn't have to be hundreds of meters) the 5 V UART is not very reliable, that's why it's converted to a higher voltage, typically +12 V for a "0" and -12 V for a "1". The data format remains the same. Then you have **RS-232** (which you actually should call EIA-232, but nobody does.)
>
> *Important*: RS-232 vs. TTL Serial Communication - SparkFun Electronics http://goo.gl/0IFYTl

The timing dependency is one of the big drawbacks of UART, and the solution is **USART**, for Universal Synchronous/Asynchronous Receiver Transmitter. This can do UART, but also a synchronous protocol. In synchronous there's not only data, but also a clock transmitted. With each bit a clock pulse tells the receiver it should latch that bit. Synchronous protocols either need a higher bandwidth, like in the case of Manchester encoding, or an extra wire for the clock, like SPI and I2C.

> Serial Programming/Typical RS232 Hardware Configuration - Wikibooks, open books for an open world http://goo.gl/uTknU6

```
RS232      +-----------+   +-----------+   +-----------+   +-----------+
Interface  | Line      |   |           |   | Interface |   |           |
-----------+ Driver /  +---+   UART    +---+ Logic     +---+    CPU    |
           | Receiver  |   |           |   |           |   |           |
           +-----------+   +-----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----------+
                                 |               |
                                 |               |
                           +-----+-----+         |
                           | Baud Rate |         |
                           | Generator +---------+
                           |           |
                           +-----------+
```

> **The UART (universal asynchronous receiver transmitter) is the heart of the serial hardware.** It is a chip or part of a chip with the purpose to convert between parallel data and serial data. RS-232 UARTs also typically add the necessary start/stop and parity bits when transmitting, and decode this information when receiving.
>
> **A UART typically operates entirely on computer logic voltage.** Its serial data input/output voltage is the computer logic voltage, not the serial line voltage. They leave the actual line interface to a particular line driver / receiver. This line driver / receiver does not necessarily need to be an RS-232 line driver / receiver, but could e.g. also be an RS-422 differential driver / receiver. This, and the fact that baud rate, parity, number of stop bits, number of data bits are programmable is the reason why UARTs are called universal. The distinction between UART and line driver / receiver blurs if they are both placed in the same chip. Such chips are typically also sold under the label 'UART'.
>
> UARTs are called asynchronous, because they don't use a special clock signal to synchronize with the the remote side. Instead, they use the start/stop bits to identify the data bits in the serial stream.
>
> Thanks to the UART the rest of the hardware, as well as the software application can deal with normal bytes to hold the communication data. It is the job of the UART to chop a byte into a series of serial bits when sending, and to assemble series of bits into a byte when receiving. UARTs typically contain eight bit wide receiver and transmission buffers. Of which not all bits might be used if e.g. a 7 bit transmission is used. Received serial data is provided in parallel in the receiver buffer, to-be-send data is written in parallel to the transmission buffer. Depending on the UART the buffers might just have a depth of one byte, or a few bytes (in the range of 15 or 16 bytes). The less deep the buffers are, the more precise the communication with the CPU needs to be. E.g. if the receiver buffer just has a depth of one byte, and the data is not fetched fast enough, the next received data can overwrite the previously received data in the buffer, and the previously received data is lost.
>
> Because of the fact that the timing on the serial interface is important, UARTs are typically connected to a baud rate generator, either an internal one in the UART chip, or an external one.

**SPI** (Serial Peripheral Interface) is another very simple serial protocol. A master sends a clock signal, and upon each clock pulse it shifts one bit out to the slave, and one bit in, coming from the slave. Signal names are therefore SCK for clock, MOSI for Master Out Slave In, and MISO for Master In Slave Out. By using SS (Slave Select) signals the master can control more than 1 slave on the bus. There are two ways to connect multiple slave devices to one master, one is mentioned above i.e. using slave select, and other is daisy chaining, it uses less hardware pins(select lines), but software gets complicated.

**I2C** (Inter-Integrated Circuit, pronounced "I squared C") is also a synchronous protocol, and it's the first we see which has some "intelligence" in it; the other ones dumbly shifted bits in and out, and that was that. I2C uses only 2 wires, one for the clock (SCL) and one for the data (SDA). That means that master and slave send data over the same wire, again controlled by the master who creates the clock signal. I2C doesn't use separate Slave Selects to select a particular device, but has addressing. The first byte sent by the master holds a 7 bit address (so that you can use 127 devices on the bus) and a read/write bit, indicating whether the next byte(s) will also come from the master of should come from the slave. After each byte receiver must send a "0" to acknowledge the reception of the byte, which the master latches with a 9th clock pulse. If the master wants to write a byte the same process repeats: the master puts bit after bit on the bus and each time gives a clock pulse to signal that the data is ready to be read. If the master wants to receive data it only generates the clock pulses. The slave has to take care that the next bit is ready when the clock pulse is given. This protocol is patented by NXP(formerly Phillips), to save licensing cost, Atmel using the word TWI(2-wire interface) which exactly same as I2C, so any AVR device will not have I2C but it will have TWI.

Two or more signals on the same wire may cause conflicts, and you would have a problem if one device sends a "1" while the other sends a "0". Therefore the bus is wired-OR'd: two resistors pull the bus to a high level, and the devices only send low levels. If they want to send a high level they simply release the bus.

**TTL** (Transistor Transistor Logic) is not a protocol. It's an older technology for digital logic, but the name is often used to refer to the 5 V supply voltage, often incorrectly referring to what should be called UART.

About each of these you can write a book, and it looks I'm well on my way. This is just a very brief overview, let us know if some things need clarification.

Comment: It seems it's just a distinction between the logical layer and the physical one. At the logical layer, the protocol is called UART, and at the physical layer, we can choose RS232 for the line driver.

Why is it wrong to say "Serial TTL"? What is the correct way to unambiguously designate the UART protocol using LVTTL/TTL voltage level? Should we only say "UART", because we don't add any "Line driver" as we are plugging ourselves directly to the original pins of the chip? But saying "UART" only is ambiguous, as we don't know whether we're using a line driver or not.

Answer (score 1):

The UART (universal asynch receiver transmitter) is/was the chip involved in moving between a parallel bus signal and serial signal.  First on I used regularly AFAIR was the 8250.  These days RS232 is being used less, and very often emulated over USB, Bluetooth and other connections, so the physical UART may no longer be present.  Properly, you should specify protocol, voltage levels, and connectors as applicable.

Comment: Thanks very much for your replies.  I'm **not** talking about **timing and signal specifications** of these two (Network controller & UART) protocols **neither** about their **access protocol** by itself since they are different protocols.
 they both are general words and regarding what communication protocol is implemented, do they take these specific names as Ethernet controller, or RS-232 controller?
thanks

Comment: @MikeW  or maybe we categorize the controllers (interface) by their usage,for example  networking controller or  paraller/serial controller?

Answer (score 1):

UART: Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter, and its sister device the USART (Synchronous/Asynchronous). These devices are, or were, commonplace in early PCs, and were used for a multitude of things. Primarily they were used for RS-232 comms, but they were sufficiently flexible to be used for RS-485 and other systems depending on how they were programmed. I haen't seen one for decades because they've been superseded by USB devices, or their functions are now implemented in software.

As to your question: refer to it by name that most closely fits its function.