# What is protocol name between Raspberry and arduino communication (by USB)?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, usb, pyserial

I am doing a project about communication between Raspberry and Arduino (by USB cable). I have read several article, some said that this protocol called RS-232, some said its UART.
Can anyone tell me that what exactly this protocol is this (connect by USB between Arduino and Raspberry and based on SerialPy Library), I need this to write on my final report.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I call it `Serial over USB`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UART controller or RS232 controller? Is UART a general word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459505/uart-controller-or-rs232-controller-is-uart-a-general-word)

Answer (score -1):

On most Arduinos, ist is indeed "serial over USB". Most USB2UART chips implement their own vendor-specific protocol.

It depends on the Arduino which variant is *actually* used, as it depends entirely on the USB2UART chip.